# URL before Referer URL PHP

Tags: php, url, session, referer

I need to get URL before HTTP_REFERER URL, like which URL user visited before he got to that last page from which I'm getting HTTP_REFERER in Observer when clicking on button.

Question is: How to get previous URL before HTTP_REFERER?

Thank you ;)

Comment: What exactly is your question? If I understand correctly, you want the URL of 2 pages back?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this one? `one_back` is previous page. `two_back` is two previous referer page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
    {
        $_SESSION['two_back'] = $_SESSION['one_back'] ?: NULL;
        $_SESSION['one_back'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?: NULL;
    }
?>
```

Comment: @ArtursNikitins you mean like this?

Comment: @Bora I think that the OP wants the info. Sessions are bound to the computer and not the server, so the OP can't even reach those variables.

Comment: He wants the HTTP_REFERER of the previous page, example, a.com->b.com->hisdomain.com so he wants a.com..

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way of doing so. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will only even be available when you're linked from somewhere else (the referer in this case). Not when you type in the URL yourself.

A way for you to get 2 pages before the current one is when you have a form of user tracking and saving it in a database.

For example, every time a user visits, you insert a row into the database with the user's location, IP and the current datetime.

A code example:

```
$db = null;

// Try to make a database connection
try
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'user', 'password');
}

// In case of failed connection,
// catch the error so it won't give away your information.
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die("Connection failed");
}

// Prepare the statement
$trackUser = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `mytable`(`IP`, `URL`, `Date`) VALUES(:ip, :url, :date)");

// Set the datetime in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
$datetime = strftime("%F %T");

// Bind everything
$trackUser->bindParam(":ip", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$trackUser->bindParam(":url", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$trackUser->bindParam(":date", $datetime, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$trackUser->execute();
```

But to get it directly from the user? You can't do that.

**From the manual**

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

the way I did it, is using nginx to store the uri as a get string

`error_page 404 $scheme://$host/404.php?referer=$request_uri;`

so `website.com/not-found` will go to `website.com/404.php?uri=/not-found`

Obviously this is a test case, but if you know have some similar issue, then u can go this route.